# Switch case in stored procedure to filter out columns

Tags: sql-server

I am puling a report of daily patients in a hospital. My `patient_ref_master` contains both old and new patients. I have taken 2 columns as new, old. I want to fetch a report in such a way that when the patient is old then the patient id should come under old column else patient id should come under new. I am binding the result of a stored procedure to a report. When I bind the result of my SP to a grid manipulating using datable in C# code it works fine. But when I try using .RDLC report I get all the patient ID's in old and new columns as well. Can I use switch case in my Stored procedure itself to filter it out. Following is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Daily_Report] '2013/08/02'
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(
      @date varchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SELECT  
    convert(varchar,Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date,105) as 'creation_Date',        
    Patient_Ref_master.Sr_No as 'sr_No',
    old_new_patient.old_new as 'old_new',
    Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID as 'Pat_ID',
    Patient_Master.Pat_FName +' '+Patient_Master.Pat_SName as 'NAME',

    Dept_ID as 'Dept_ID',
    Dept_Master.Dept_Name as 'Dept_Name',
    Doc_Master.Doc_ID as 'Doc_Master',
    Doc_Master.Doc_FName+' '+Doc_Master.Doc_SName as 'Doc_Name',
    Patient_Master.Pat_Addr as 'addr',
    Gender_master.Name1 as 'Pat_Sex',
    Patient_Master.Age as 'age'


    FROM Patient_Ref_master             
    left join dbo.old_new_patient on dbo.old_new_patient.code=Patient_Ref_master.old_new   
    left join dbo.Dept_Master  on   Dept_Master.Dept_code  =   Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID
    left join Patient_Master on Patient_Master.Pat_Code=Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID 
    left join Doc_Master on Doc_Master.Doc_ID=Patient_Ref_master.Doc_ID 
    left join Gender_master on Gender_master.Code=Patient_Master.Pat_Sex
 where         
 Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date=@date
--MONTH(Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date)=@month and Dept_ID=@dept

    order by Patient_Ref_master.Sr_No asc


I want something like the following. where 1st row has the patient for 2nd aug under Patient_ID_New column because he is new and 2nd line because he is old. I want a blank space like 1st row in Patient_Id_Old coumn


  Date          No  Patient_ID_New  Patient ID Old
  02-08-2013    11  11                            
  02-08-2013    13                           1
```

Comment: Have you tried the `CASE` expression? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: What are the table structures...

Comment: @YuxiuLi : Actually I have never used case in SP. I KNow the syntax, but how to use here because I am getting Pat_ID in the same SP Dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use case statemnet for the following:

```
 Select 
      (Case when "condition for oldpatient" Then PatientName Else Null End) Old_Patient,
      (Case when "condition for Newpatient" Then PatientName Else Null End) New_Patient
 From TableName
```

Comment: What are the Old_Patient and New_patient at the end of each line.?

Comment: These are column Names, you can change it as per your convenience.

Comment: Super..!!! Super..!!! It worked .Please be available if in future I need any help ..!! ;-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I get it. I think this is what you want...

```
SELECT  
    convert(varchar,Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date,105) as 'creation_Date',        
    Patient_Ref_master.Sr_No as 'sr_No',
    Case When old_new_patient.old_new = 0x1 Then old_new_patient.old_new
        Else Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID
    End as 'Pat_ID',
    Patient_Master.Pat_FName +' '+Patient_Master.Pat_SName as 'NAME',
```